# O que significa "se ligar"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, significado, gíria

Eu conheço o verbo *ligar* mas qual o significado de *"se ligar"*?

Exemplo em um diálogo:

> - Sabia que você tá revirando minha cabeça?
> - Me liguei
> - Que maneiro que você se ligou! Tô afim de te levar pra namorar...
> - Demorou!

Fonte: [MV Bill - Um Tiro](https://youtu.be/mTPsz7k0CXY?t=3m4s)

Comment: Neste caso significa "percebi", hoje usa-se 'Me toquei', "Me dei conta", "Tô sabendo", "Saquei"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O significado é "prestar atenção", é provável que seja uma gíria, assim como "você é desligado(a)", que neste caso seria a pessoa que precisa "ligar" pois é desatenta.

E provavelmente formou ou é derivado outras gírias como:

- *Se liga na bolinha do zóio*

  Prestar atenção a uma conversa, ficar atento.
- *Se liga na mexerica*

  Fique esperto, ou preste atenção.

Acredito que usado apenas no Brasil.

Fonte:

- http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/folhinha/dicas/di28020407.htm
- http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/se%20liga/

Comment: Às vezes é só "veja" mesmo: *se liga nisto aqui*.

Comment: De referir que só se usa no Brasil

Comment: @JorgeB. Não mencionei isto devido a musica ser brasileira, mas vou editar.

Comment: @bfavaretto acho que a ideia de *"veja"* é a mesma de pedir atenção da pessoa pra *"ver"*.

Comment: Sim, é *quase* a mesma ideia (só que prestar atenção exige mais... atenção). Divertidas as duas outras gírias que você citou, eu não conhecia :)