# Qual é o significado de “Se Ligar a maquina”?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática

Já sei como usar ***se*** antes de verbo e vi [essa pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/520/o-que-significa-se-ligar) . Mais vi um caso que me deixou confuso.

> — Como é que se liga a máquina?
>
> — Apertando o botão ligue.

Posso também dizer o seguinte?

> Como é que se liga a máquina?

Comment: acho que isso é mais informal. Seria algo como: 
"Com é que a máquina é ligada?" Ou "Como é que a máquina pode ser ligada?"

Comment: Esse "se ligar" da pergunta relacionada é uma gíria.

Comment: Tens aqui [uma pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/constru%c3%a7%c3%a3o-da-voz-passiva-passive-voice-construction) sobre esse teu *se*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que há duas hipóteses para "se ligar a máquina". Por questão de concordância pronominal, vou usar "ligar-se a máquina", mas é equivalente a "se ligar a máquina".

#### Voz Passiva Sintética

Voz passiva é quando a ação é feita e não faz; voz ativa: "eu amo Joliscreide", voz passiva: "Joliscreide é amada por mim". Para veres mais (vale a pena), lê em [conjugação.com.br](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/vozes-verbais/#:%7E:text=Os%20verbos%20apresentam%20flex%C3%A3o%20em,%3A%20ativa%2C%20passiva%20e%20reflexiva).

Há duas formas de voz passiva, sintética e analítica; voz passiva **analítica**: "a ideia foi executada", voz passiva **sintética**: "executou-se a ideia". Vale notar que "foi" tem a mesma conjugação verbal de "executou".

Então, "**ligar**-se a máquina" = "a máquina **ser** ligada".

#### Pronome Indefinido "se"

Outra hipótese é o uso de "se" como pronome indefinido (Priberam); ex.: "hoje, se trabalha no domingo", que é diferente de "hoje, é trabalhado no domingo".

Esse "se" pode ser trocado por "(vo)cê": "hoje, você trabalha no domingo", porém não pode ser voz passiva, pois, é um verbo intransitivo nesse caso. Então, só há 1 interpretação.

Assim, "ligar-se a máquina" = "alguém/você ligar a máquina".

#### Qual?

Neste caso, vou ser opinativo. Ambos os usos que mencionei são muito comuns tanto na língua formal falada ou escrita, tanto na língua informal escrita ou falada; e ambas as "traduções de linguagem" funcionam.

1. "Como é que se liga a máquina?";
2. "como é que a máquina é ligada?";
3. "como é que alguém/você liga a máquina?".

Como se *vê*, você *vê* ou *é* visto, 2 e 3 são funcionais — a respeito duma "tradução de linguagem" de 1 — e provavelmente receberiam a mesma resposta, porém, quem perguntou (1) provavelmente quis saber como ligar a máquina, então, é mais provável que 1 = 3 do que 1 = 2.

Por exemplo, "como se faz café?" pode ser 1) "[...] é feito café [...]" ou 2) "[...] você/alguém faz café?". Se eu perguntar esse (1), posso receber a resposta "os fazendeiros plantam, regam… "; se eu perguntar este (2), posso receber a resposta "apertando o botão e *voilà*, tens um cafezinho!". Então, a "tradução" é extremamente sensível a contexto.

#### Notas Finais

Vi alguns dizendo, nos comentários, que "como se liga a máquina" é informal, mas não é, nem "como a máquina é ligada" e "como você/alguém liga a máquina". Porém, "como é que" e "como que" são informais, sendo apenas "como" formal, pois têm basicamente o mesmo significado.

"Ligar" pode ser pronominal, tendo significado de prestar atenção, como em "se liga, meu irmão!". Acho que apenas essa forma é informal.

Comment: Sim, as duas possibilidade aqui são passiva sintética e voz ativa com o pronome indefinido *se*. Mas a passiva só funciona com verbos transitivos diretos: podes dizer  "o bolo é saboreado" (= "saboreia-se o bolo") mas não *"o bolo é gostado" (é *gostar **de** (o bolo);* não é transitivo direto). Mesma coisa no exemplo "trabalha-se ao domingo": *trabalhar* é aí intransitivo; logo não admite passiva. Podes ver perguntas sobre a passiva aqui no site (comentário à pergunta).

Comment: @Jacinto, então "trabalha-se" só pode ser "você/alguém trabalha"? Interessante.

Comment: @Jacinto, "gostou-se do bolo" (voz passiva sintética) é permitido?

Comment: *Gostou-se do bolo* e *trabalha-se* são possíveis, mas o *se* é pronome indefinido: =  pessoas não especificadas gostaram do bolo/trabalham. Para ser passiva o verbo tem de ser transitivo direto. Voz ativa: *X faz Y* (Y é complemento direto) passa na passiva a *Y é feito (por X)* ou *faz-se Y* (Y é sujeito). Em *Alguém gostou do bolo* (*bolo* é complemento oblíquo) e *alguém trabalha ao domingo* não há complemento direto para servir de sujeito na passiva.

Comment: @Jacinto, mas "gostou-se do bolo" já não estaria por causa de "de"; assim como "do bolo foi gostado"?

Comment: @Jacinto, ok. "Gostou-se do bolo" é obviamente voz ATIVA, desculpa. Mas "do bolo foi gostado", eu não sei.

Comment: Mas alguém diz "do bolo foi gostado"? Eu nunca ouvi ou li. Se se disser nalgum lado, não é língua padrão. Podes dizer, "do bolo foi tirada uma fatia (pelo João)" = "foi tirada uma fatia do bolo (pelo João), que na voz ativa fica, "O João tirou uma fatia do bolo", porque *tirar* é transitivo direto: *tirar uma fatia*. Verbos com complementos obblíquos (ligam-se ao complemento por preposição, como *gostar **de** algo*) não admitem passiva.

Comment: @Jacinto, minha mãe, familiares e amigos falam desse jeito, comigo incluso.

Comment: Isso  não é padrão nem sequer norma culta. Vê por exemplo no [Gramaticalhas](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8046/qual-%c3%a9-o-significado-de-se-ligar-a-maquina/8047?noredirect=1#comment18084_8047): "só tem voz passiva um verbo transitivo direto ou transitivo direto e indireto (bitransitivo)" e "por isso, a frase 'O juiz não gostou do depoimento' não tem voz passiva". O próprio site que tu linkas diz isso, que o objeto direto da voz ativa passa a sujeito da passiva; logo verbos sem o objeto direto -- como *gostar (de algo)* -- não têm passiva.

Comment: @Jacinto, eu concordo que apenas verbos transitivos direto podem ser voz de passiva, eu não estava duvidando de ti sobre isso.

Comment: Então e vais deixar o "o bolo é gostado por mim" e "hoje, é trabalhado ao domingo" na tua resposta? Deverias substituí-los por exemplos corretos.

Comment: @Jacinto, tinha me esquecido. Obrigado.

Comment: @Jacinto, "hoje, é trabalhado no domingo" é obviamente diferente de "hoje, trabalha-se no domingo', então, acho que não há necessidade de trocar esse. Agora vi um erro em relação a exemplos, trocá-lo-hei!